# Complicated array comparison

Tags: php, mysql

1- I'm building a comparison app which compares the relationship between two users.
If the user A and user B has the same country address then it will print alert to any of the same similar values.

2- There is another issue which is some users has multiple addresses for example user A has address x1 and user b has address x1 and address x2, in this scenario how do I compare user A's address with the multiple addresses with user B and alert that the address x1 is matched between the two users?

**here is the queries for both users**

```
$query1 = "
  SELECT
    a.PID, a.`Name`, a.Avatar, a.Email,
    b.City, a.LDate, b.Country, b.MPhone,
    b.Gender, b.Birthday
  FROM
    `Profile` AS a
    LEFT JOIN Details AS b ON a.PID = b.PID
  WHERE
    a.PID = '1'
";
$UserInfo1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query1);
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($UserInfo1) ){
  $Avatar1 = "{$row['Avatar']}";
  $Name1 = "{$row['Name']}";
  $Email1 = "{$row['Email']}";
  $Country1 = "{$row['Country']}</td>";
  $MPhone1 = "{$row['MPhone']}</td>";
  $Gender1 = "{$row['Gender']}</td>";
  $City1 = "{$row['City']}</td>";
  $Birthday1 = "{$row['Birthday']}</td>";
    }
  $query2 = "
  SELECT
    a.PID, a.`Name`, a.Avatar, a.Email,
    b.City, a.LDate, b.Country, b.MPhone,
    b.Gender, b.Birthday
  FROM
    `Profile` AS a
    LEFT JOIN Details AS b ON a.PID = b.PID
  WHERE
    a.PID = '2'
";
  $UserInfo2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query2);
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($UserInfo2) ){
  $Avatar2 = "{$row['Avatar']}";
  $Name2 = "{$row['Name']}";
  $Email2 = "{$row['Email']}";
  $Country2 = "{$row['Country']}</td>";
  $MPhone2 = "{$row['MPhone']}</td>";
  $Gender2 = "{$row['Gender']}</td>";
  $City2 = "{$row['City']}</td>";
  $Birthday2 = "{$row['Birthday']}</td>";
    }
```

3- The final results is that I want to make flowchart and point the matched information to each other something like this screenshot:

[image]

What would be the best and simplest way to make this comparison in php or Mysql?

Your help is highly needed and appreciated.

Comment: Matching is what sql is really great for. Why do you want to do this in php?

Comment: PHP or sql. I have edited the question.

Keen to get a great solution.

If you could help that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Query like: `SELECT u1.PID,u2.PID,u1.country FROM Details u1 INNER JOIN Details u2 ON (u1.country=u2.country) WHERE u1.PID=1 AND u2.PID=2` should give you all matching countries for these two users. Then you can run your  queries to get more user details.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Yuri, but this isn&#39;t meeting my requirements, as country is just an example. I want to match punch of other values like phone citiy.
I&#39;m in the middle of solving it in tedious way, I&#39;ll post it as an answer so others will have better understanding of what is my requirements.